# Is there any url params available for redirect after send an email in gmail url?

Tags: email, url, gmail

I have a link in my web-app for user sending an email. The URL looks like this below :

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&to={your@email.com}&fs=1&tf=1
```

When user click that link, they can compose an email with compose mail view. After a user click the 'send email' button, the page will appear blank.

So my question, Are there any URL parameters that support redirection instead of giving the user blank page after sending email? I couldn't found any documentation for Gmail URL parameters just like `view`, `to`, `fs`, `tf`. I wonder is there any url parameter for example `redirect_to=myapps.com`.

Comment: Are you talking about from within the gmail website? Or what? This question is a little unclear on details at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming. If I am mistaken, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58750938/edit) and add details about how it relates to programming.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for my unclear question. I'm building an app that allow user to compose an email, I provided it via url / link. the example url is on the description. If you tried that, after sending an email, the page appears blank. I wonder if google has another url params for redirect back to my apps, something like `&redirect_to=https://myapps.com` or something else @TylerH @Chipster